# Convert a movieclip to a custom class extending movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

I have a coin `MovieClip` which revolves around different orbits in my puzzle game.

Well, my problem is I need to use my

> currentCoin

which is a

```
private var currentCoin:MovieClip
```

to use the attributes and methods of the `DynamicMovie` custom as3 class which extends from `flash.display.MovieClip`

Also,  will I be able to add dynamic properties to

```
private var currentCoin:DynamicMovie
```

like

```
mcCurrentCoin["isTravelling"] = true;
```

after I convert this as a `Dynamic Movie`?

Thanks,

Vishnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Kodiak says it's right, MovieClip is a dynamic class, so you can add properties on the fly. You don't need a custom class to do it. But if you have defined methods for your class, then you do need a custom class.

If your question is HOW to convert a library object to a custom class instead of a movieclip, just right click on it in the library, and in the Export for ActionScript option define as class name "DynamicMovie" and as base class "flash.display.MovieClip". if your class it's completely created by code, just let it extend MovieClip.

Answer (score 2):

`MovieClip` is a dynamic class, so you can already add properties on the fly. If you extend `MovieClip` and want to keep this behaviour (which is not really OOP), you just have to declare your class as dynamic:

```
public dynamic class DynamicMovie extends MovieClip
```

But you should really reconsider it and declare the variables you need (such as `isTravelling`) in your custom class.

Comment: Thanks for that, But you did not really answer my question. I want to use both MovieClip and DynamicMovie attributes and properties from the new custom class's object instance.